# Why does Nicolas Cage's character laugh at guy's name in Bad Lieutenant?

Tags: plot-explanation, bad-lieutenant-new-orleans

In *Bad Lieutenant: Port of Call New Orleans* Terence (played by Nicolas Cage) finds the name of one of the guy's he's looking for hilarious! The guy is nicknamed G. Every time he mentions it, he laughs a little.

Is this just a funny unexplained quirk or there's a joke I'm not getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I love this film and having watched it on multiple occasions following its release I believe it is just a personal quirk as opposed to having any deeper significance.

'G' is possibly the most cliched nickname one can have in contemporary American urban crime circles and indeed, the legendary '[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=G)' lists its top definition of 'G' as a prison orientated shortened form of 'gansta'/gangster.

As Terrance is often high on powder or crack cocaine when he is not using cannabis or opiates and opioids, like many others who use such drugs he finds profound hilarity within things that most others would consider trivial or of no particular note.

Comment: G being very clichéd makes a lot of sense, though. Great movie indeed!

Comment: I am sorry for what was at least in part a subjective answer, but as one of Herzog's 'lighter' pieces I have come across very little commentary regarding BL:POCNO and have used my familiarity with the film to provide what seems to me like the most logical in universe answer. Good question though and welcome to the site!

Comment: No that's a great answer, I didn't know G stand for gangsta (and that's apparently obvious to people in the known of the US culture) and that explanation makes a lot of sense until there's a competing explanation.

Comment: G = Gangsta.  OG = Original Gangsta (meaning, you were there "at the beginning").  Two very cliched nicknames in American movies/culture.

Comment: This answer made me look up the difference between "opiates" and "opioids." +1